# Formulas in extjs viewmodel

Tags: extjs, formula, viewmodel

I've got a simple viewmodel with a formula (pretty much cut and paste from sencha docs), but it formulas are not working.

A full example is here :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/3lpa

Summarised :

```
Ext.define('vm', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
formulas: {
    bar: function (get) {
      return true;
    }
}});
```

...

vm.get('bar')

When executed - this returns "null", not "true"
Also - the vm.getFormulas() is empty.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Formula calculation is managed by ExtJS in a complicated way to optimize performance. In your example ExtJS does not see a reason to calculate your formula. Try this code, as you see the `bind` statement references the ViewModel data, so it will be calculated correctly:

```
Ext.define('vm', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.vm',
    formulas: {
        bar: function (get) {
          return true;
        }
    }})

Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',
    launch : function() {
        var component =Ext.create({
            xtype: 'component',
            bind: {
                html: '{bar}'
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            viewModel: {
                type: 'vm'
            }
        });
    }
});
```